# Не работает «Ctrl + /» в VS Code. Как исправить?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Рассказываю как все делаю подробно, уже не знаю где здесь можно ошибиться.

1. Навожу курсор на ту строку, которую хочу закомментировать (вначале или в конце).
2. Нажимаю комбинацию <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.
3. Ничего не сработало.
   Могу комментировать только вручную, несмотря на то, что в keyboard shortcats команда <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> есть. В чем может быть проблема?

VS Code уже был удален и заново переустановлен - не помогло.

P.S. В инете есть информация о том, что такое поведение возможно из-за того, что команды операционной системы переопределяют команды VS Code. Возникает вопрос: как вообще увидеть команды моей ОС? Как это исправить?

Comment: У каждого DE свои глобальные хоткеи, которые могут конфликтовать. Попробуйте найти их в системных настройках. Я обычно всегда всё удаляю и оставляю только те, которые используют super в качестве модификатора.

Comment: @Beast Winterwolf зашла посмотреть совпадающие хоткеи. Они действительно [были](https://prnt.sc/101qtor), но удалив совпадения (toggleExplainMode) все также - изменений нет.

Comment: Так нужно было удалить их не в Code, а в системе.

Comment: Вы наверное меня не так поняли. Я имел ввиду вот эти хоткеи: https://i.imgur.com/0Oebiz4.png

Comment: @Beast Winterwolf не подскажете где примерно находится этот файл с хоткеями? Это вы смотрите в keybindings.json? Если да, то у меня его нет (по крайней мере по этому пути - Windows: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User)

Comment: Я предположил, что сочетания клавиш вашей операционной системы (или другой внешней программы) конфликтуют с VSCode. У каждого дистрибутива Linux свои хоткеи, там такое часто бывает, но насчёт Windows ничего не знаю.

Comment: Любая программа, будь-то музыкальный плеер или та, которой вы делали скриншот, может легко переопределить глобальные сочетания клавиш под себя. Попробуйте завершить все пользовательские процессы в диспетчере задач и затем запустить vscode.

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас русская версия VS , попробуйте поставить английскую(либо наоборот). Иногда бывает что VSCode определяет любую раскладу клавиатуры как русскую. Банально, но может быть и из-за этого. Также проверьте определен ли у Вас данный хоткей. Также насколько я знаю для многострочного комментария так же есть <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. P.S поискал на других источниках вашу проблему, и наткнулся на занимательную статью, которая называется "Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code" где расписаны все привязки клавиш, и их настройки. Может быть там Вы сможете найти конкретный ответ, и все у Вас получится. Также там вроде как есть отдельный заголовок где детектят конфликты.

Comment: У меня английская версия. Ctrl+Shift+A тоже не работает. А как и где проверить хоткей? Если я правильно понимаю, я скорее всего уже проверила. В keyboard shortcats эта комбинация есть

Answer (score 1):

Тупо переопределил в настройках сочетание клавиш и заработало.

Настройки > Сочетание клавиш > editor.action.commentLine > ctrl+numpad_divide

editor.action.commentLine или закомментировать или раскомментировать строку

Comment: Что именно вы переопределили?

Comment: @Eva, возможно, он имеет в виду, что надо посмотреть переопределения клавиш - может быть что-то ещё стоит на это сочетание.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @Qwertiy да, возможно) надо будет ещё покопаться. Может есть какие-то проги, которые позволяют изменять сочетания клавиш. Сейчас отложила немного эту проблему т.к. комп в ремонте

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, стоит посмотреть уже переопределенные клавиши тут:

```
Windows: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User

Linux: /home/<username>/.config/Code/User
```

в файле keybindings.json

Answer (score 0):

Возникла такая же проблема. Решил переназначением в самом приложении Visual Studio Code > Файл > Настройки > Сочетания клавиш (Ctrl+K). После переназначения, ранее назначенная клавиша "/" сменилась на "NumPad_Divide"

[image: скриншот переназначения]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Команду shift + alt + a . Мне помогло!

Comment: об этом же написано в тексте одного из ответов. что нового добавляет сюда ваш ответ? изложите это, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте ответа, нажав [edit]